# How Can I Close C File without Saving Info to Files

Tags: c, file

So in my program I prompt the user to choose whether to exit with saving info written to a file or exit without saving ..But My Problem when I use exit() or return; the files opened are closed automatically(Saved) ..so how can i stop this from hapenning is there another function ?

Comment: By only writing the data to file when user says OK.

Comment: Write the file changes/info to be added to a buffer instead, then output buffer to file if and only if user wants you to.

Comment: the problem is when the user enters info it is stored in an array of struct having many members so It can be problamatic to store temporary info

Answer (score 3):

This is the same problem I tackled while making my notepad app on C. Don't write to file as soon as you get the input. Store all the user input in a big array, `char input[100]`, and then 
if the user says no, close the file and `return 0;`
if the user says yes, `fprintf(file,"%s",input);`, and then close the file.

To your doubt:
@ZeyadIbrahim a good thing about structs(non-node struct) is it’s easily accessible. If user says yes store all Info in a local array variable and then put its contents to the struct, this will make life easier. So don’t directly write into a struct, first put in a variable and then into struct and then based upon users input store in file.

Comment: the problem is when the user enters info it is stored in an array of struct having many members so It can be problamatic to store temporary info

Comment: First store in variable, then put it into the struct and the. Put it into file, you don’t have to write directly in the struct

Answer (score -1):

When your app starts, check if there is a .bak file.
If there is, delete any main file, copy the bak file to a new main file.
If there is no bak file, make one by renaming main to bak and copying bak to a new main.

Then run you app, writing/appending/whatever the main file.
If your user wants to save the new data, close the main file and then delete the bak file.
If your user does not want to save, delete the main file.

Comment: the problem is when the user enters info it is stored in an array of struct having many members so It can be problamatic to store temporary info